# How to cast a Clerk userId to a MongoDB ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, clerk

In the following code, is there a way to cast the clerk userId to an ObjectId? In this cased, clerkId is user_2eImnitE0bBq3mk06dsyh6u3sey and I need it to be something like 65d7b4e1b10459878c61cc6b.

This is because apparently sessionClaims in Clerk doesn't have userId on it, just user_sub, so this returns me null and I need to compare the Clerk userId on the database. Any help, please?

```
import EventForm from "@/components/shared/EventForm";
import { auth } from "@clerk/nextjs";

const CreateEvent = () => {
  const { userId } = auth();

  //original code
  const { sessionClaims } = auth();
  const userID = sessionClaims?.userId as string;

  return (
    <>
      <section className="bg-primary-50 bg-dotted-pattern bg-cover bg-center py-5 md:py-10">
        <h3 className="wrapper h3-bold text-center sm:text-left">
          Create Event
        </h3>
      </section>

      <div className="wrapper my-8">
        {/* original code */}
        <EventForm userId={userID} type="Create" />
        <EventForm userId={userId as string} type="Create" />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default CreateEvent;
```

Comment: _"I need to compare the Clerk userId on the database"_ Then how you convert the clerkId `user_2eImn...` will need to match what is already stored in the DB. How was that done? If nothing has already been done, and you'll be saving this for the first time, then choose some Javascript hash function which returns >= 24 Hex characters, trim it to 24 hex chars and then use `{ $toObjectID: hex24String }`.

Comment: there's also a clerkID in the db, shouldn't it be able to compare with userId from auth()?